# React Native Elements ListItem won't show switch button

Tags: javascript, user-interface, react-native, listitem

I'm trying to create a settings menu for a react native project I am working on, and for the majority of my UI I am using react native elements.  One of the settings I need is a boolean value, so I want to use a switch in order to change that value.  However I can not get the switch to even show up on the list item.

Here are my imports in my settings.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Dimensions,  StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {ListItem,  Input, Button } from 'react-native-elements';
```

When I try to create a a List Item with a switch, Like so:

```
<ListItem
      switch
      title="Active"
      switched = {this.state.active}
/>
```

I get an error that says: "TypeError: IN this environment the sources for assign MUST be an object. This error is a performance optimization and not spec compliant"

If I try to create a ListItem like this:

```
<ListItem
      switchButton
      title="Active"
      switched = {this.state.active}
/>
```

The item shows up but there is no switch.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

First i think there is no **switch** props in Lists.

Second if you need to display the switchButton you need to add the hideChevron prop as well.

Example:

```
       <List>
          <ListItem
            switchButton
            title=":( Where is my switch?"
            onSwitch={e => console.warning(e)}
          />
          <ListItem
            switchButton
            hideChevron
            title=":) Here it is!"
            onSwitch={() => {}}
          />
        </List>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, however I am still not getting any results.  I'm not sure if it is because my ListItem's are not included in a List component from RNE, however I do believe the version I am using of RNE does not include lists anymore.